# LLVM StoreInst and AllocaInst

Tags: c++, llvm, llvm-ir, llvm-c++-api

I am trying to write a simple interpreter.

I am trying to generate LLVM IR for assignment operation. The code for the generation part looks like this

```
llvm::Value* codeGenSymTab(llvm::LLVMContext& context) {
    printf("\n CodeGen SymTab \n");
    Value *num = ConstantInt::get(Type::getInt64Ty(context), aTable.value, true);
    Value *alloc = new AllocaInst(IntegerType::get(context, 32), aTable.variableName,entry);
    StoreInst *ptr = new StoreInst(num,alloc,false,entry);
}
```

Here goes the SymTab definition:

```
struct SymTab {
     char* variableName;
     int value; 
     llvm::Value* (*codeGen)(llvm::LLVMContext& context);   
};
```

When I try to execute the output file,I get the following error:

```
Assertion failed: (getOperand(0)->getType() == cast<PointerType>(getOperand(1)->getType())->getElementType() && "Ptr must be a pointer to Val type!"), function AssertOK, file Instructions.cpp, line 1084.
Abort trap: 6
```

Can you help me resolve it ?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You try to store a value of type `i64` into an address of type `i32*`, and these don't match.

You can fix this by using the same type - or preferably, the actual same object:

```
IntegerType *int_type = Type::getInt64Ty(context);
Value *num = ConstantInt::get(int_type, aTable.value, true);
Value *alloc = new AllocaInst(int_type, aTable.variableName, entry);
StoreInst *ptr = new StoreInst(num,alloc,false,entry);
```

Comment: if we do not have the entry but we have the builder, can we still apply this?